# What is wrong with my air conditioner

Tags: hvac

I have been using my air conditioner on and off all summer. The weather hasn't been really that bad this year. But now that the weather is reaching high 80s, my air conditioner decides to die on me.

The unit turns on and the compressor fan outside works. However, the air doesn't  come out of the vents. And the little air that does come out is not cold. Usually the little area where the UIT is  gets very cold.

I don't know if that is the blower or the motor.

Comment: Descreaming version: We need more info here. Is this a window unit? Split unit? Central air? If it's a window unit, have you ever cleaned it? They need regular cleaning to allow airflow through the exterior fins.

Comment: Revise the title to convey the gist of your question: "My air conditioner turns on. The compressor fan outside spins. Cold air doesn't come out of the vents. How can I figure out what is wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

If there is **no** air coming out of the vents, you'll want to check to make sure the blower fan in on. If it's not, you'll have to investigate why (failed motor, failed wiring, etc.). If the blower is on, you'll want to figure out why the air is being blocked. Blockages may be caused by, but are not limited to:

- Closed dampers
- Blockage in the ducts
- Closed registers
- Blocked returns
- Disconnected ducting
- Dirty filter(s)
- Dirt, grime, filth, and/or debris in the ducts

If there is a small amount of air, you'll want to make sure the blower is running at the proper speed. You'll also want to look for restrictions in the ducting. Which may include, but not limited to:

- Closed dampers
- Blocked returns
- Closed registers
- Blockage in ducts
- Dirty filter(s)
- Disconnected ducts
- Dirt, grime, filth, and/or debris in the ducts

Answer (score -2):

You've lost power to the outdoor unit. Check the breaker or fuses.